# Unable to initialize class variables using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have large XML file that contains many node & sub node.
I am trying to get particular details & save it.
I paste code as follows. 
XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CLabelContainer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Labels>
    <LabelList>
      <CLabel>
        <VehicleLabel>
          <ImageName>image1.bmp</ImageName>
          <BoundingRect>
            <X>433</X>
            <Y>205</Y>
            <Width>39</Width>
            <Height>42</Height>
          </BoundingRect>
        </VehicleLabel>
      </CLabel>
      .
     & So on... 
      .
      <CLabel>
        <VehicleLabel>
          <ImageName>image20.bmp</ImageName>
          <BoundingRect>
            <X>425</X>
            <Y>305</Y>
            <Width>30</Width>
            <Height>46</Height>
          </BoundingRect>
        </VehicleLabel>
      </CLabel>
    </LabelList>
  </Labels>
</CLabelContainer>
```

Here is target XML

```
    class cROI
{
    public Int16 iX { get; set; }
    public Int16 iY { get; set; }
    public Int16 iWidth { get; set; }
    public Int16 iHeight { get; set; }

    public cROI(Int16 iX, Int16 iY, Int16 iWidth, Int16 iHeight)
    {
        this.iX = iX;
        this.iY = iY;
        this.iWidth = iWidth;
        this.iHeight = iHeight;
        Console.WriteLine("{3}, {1}, {2}, {0}", this.iX, this.iY, this.iWidth, this.iHeight);
    }

    public cROI()
    {
       // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }
}
```

LINQ to XML in main function.....

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         XDocument xXmlDoc = XDocument.Load("C:/Users/User1/Desktop/abc.xml");
        var m_cROI = from ROI in xXmlDoc.Descendants("CLabelContainer") select new cROI
         {
           iX = Int16.Parse(ROI.Element("Labels").Element("LabelList").Element("CLabel").Element("VehicleLabel").Element("BoundingRect").Element("X").Value),
           iY = Int16.Parse(ROI.Element("Labels").Element("LabelList").Element("CLabel").Element("VehicleLabel").Element("BoundingRect").Element("Y").Value),
           iWidth = Int16.Parse(ROI.Element("Labels").Element("LabelList").Element("CLabel").Element("VehicleLabel").Element("BoundingRect").Element("iWidth").Value),
           iHeight = Int16.Parse(ROI.Element("Labels").Element("LabelList").Element("CLabel").Element("VehicleLabel").Element("BoundingRect").Element("iHeight").Value),
         };
```

I get no output. (Press any key to continue....)

Note : is it possible to create a list of cROI & fill all 20 image bounding rectangle elements ?? Above, as test purpose, i am trying with one element only.

Edit : I tried to call with parameterised constructor, instead of " select new ROI {....}", "Select new ROI( {....} )". No result

Comment: You get no output?  Have you *tried* debugging?

Comment: Yes. Debug control at var m_cROI = ...... & then end of main, so finally no output

Comment: Well, that doesn't shine any light on the situation. You should [edit] and say what you observed during debugging and why it was not what you expected.

Comment: When i press F10 / F11 at line " var  m_cROI = from..... ", it comes directly to next closing bracket. Never seen going inside & execute iX,iY, iWidth, iHeight etc...
Then output console screen "Enter any key to continue...."
I think either it is not accessible the XML contents or unable to reach till class variables

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expecting to see the `Console.WriteLine(...` output from the `public cROI(Int16 iX, Int16 iY, Int16 iWidth, Int16 iHeight)` constructor, but you are not, for the following reasons:

1. You are not calling this constructor.  Instead, you are calling the parameterless constructor, then filling in the properties with an [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx).
2. Linq queries are [lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx).  Thus results are not actually evaluated until requested.
3. You have the wrong names for the width and height elements in the XML.  They are `<Width>30</Width>` and `<Height>46</Height>` whereas your code expects `<iWidth>30</iWidth>` and `<iHeight>46</iHeight>`.  (With the wrong names, your code will throw a `NullReferenceException`.)

Putting these together, the following should produce the console output you expect:

```
        var m_cROI = from ROI in xXmlDoc.Descendants("CLabelContainer")
                     select new cROI
                     ( // Use the explicit constructor
                         Int16.Parse(ROI.Element("Labels").Element("LabelList").Element("CLabel").Element("VehicleLabel").Element("BoundingRect").Element("X").Value),
                         Int16.Parse(ROI.Element("Labels").Element("LabelList").Element("CLabel").Element("VehicleLabel").Element("BoundingRect").Element("Y").Value),
                         Int16.Parse(ROI.Element("Labels").Element("LabelList").Element("CLabel").Element("VehicleLabel").Element("BoundingRect").Element("Width").Value),
                         Int16.Parse(ROI.Element("Labels").Element("LabelList").Element("CLabel").Element("VehicleLabel").Element("BoundingRect").Element("Height").Value)
                     );
        var result = m_cROI.ToList(); // Actually evaluate the query.
```

**Update**

To get all `VehicleLabel` bounding rectangles, you can use [`XPathSelectElements`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find all `BoundingRect` nodes.

if `CLabelContainer` *is* the root document node (which it is in your example), then the most efficient query would be:

```
        var query = from rect in xXmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/CLabelContainer/Labels/LabelList/CLabel/VehicleLabel/BoundingRect")
                    select new cROI
                    (
                         Int16.Parse(rect.Element("X").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
                         Int16.Parse(rect.Element("Y").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
                         Int16.Parse(rect.Element("Width").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
                         Int16.Parse(rect.Element("Height").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
                    );
        var AllBoundingRect = query.ToList();
```

if `CLabelContainer` is *not* the root document node, you can do:

```
        var query = from rect in xXmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("//CLabelContainer/Labels/LabelList/CLabel/VehicleLabel/BoundingRect")
                    select new cROI
                    (
                         Int16.Parse(rect.Element("X").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
                         Int16.Parse(rect.Element("Y").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
                         Int16.Parse(rect.Element("Width").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
                         Int16.Parse(rect.Element("Height").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
                    );
        var AllBoundingRect = query.ToList();
```

Where the "//" string means "search recursively throughout the document for the following chain of nodes".  It is equivalent to:

```
        var query = from rect in xXmlDoc.Descendants("CLabelContainer").Elements("Labels").Elements("LabelList").Elements("CLabel").Elements("VehicleLabel").Elements("BoundingRect")
                    select new cROI
                    (
                         Int16.Parse(rect.Element("X").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
                         Int16.Parse(rect.Element("Y").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
                         Int16.Parse(rect.Element("Width").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
                         Int16.Parse(rect.Element("Height").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
                    );
        var AllBoundingRect = query.ToList();
```

Note I am parsing the numbers using the [invariant culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.invariantinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (i.e. not localized to a specific language or country) which is almost always the correct way to parse data exchange files such as XML.

Comment: Got the first bounding rect of image1. Thanks.
Can i get List<cROI> AllBoundingRect = new List<cROI>() ?

Comment: Excellent guidance..... Thanks !!
Following above, i have posted another question. If possible, follow,
http://stackoverflow.com/q/30637711/3042916

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the parameterless constructor of the cRoi class, and using property initializers to populate the class. This way, you won't hit the Console.WriteLine code in the constructor that takes parameters.

To call the constructor, use this syntax

```
 var m_cROI = from ROI in xXmlDoc.Descendants("CLabelContainer") select new cROI
         (
           iX = Int16.Parse(ROI.Element("Labels").Element("LabelList").Element("CLabel").Element("VehicleLabel").Element("BoundingRect").Element("X").Value),
           iY = Int16.Parse(ROI.Element("Labels").Element("LabelList").Element("CLabel").Element("VehicleLabel").Element("BoundingRect").Element("Y").Value),
           iWidth = Int16.Parse(ROI.Element("Labels").Element("LabelList").Element("CLabel").Element("VehicleLabel").Element("BoundingRect").Element("iWidth").Value),
           iHeight = Int16.Parse(ROI.Element("Labels").Element("LabelList").Element("CLabel").Element("VehicleLabel").Element("BoundingRect").Element("iHeight").Value),
        );
```

You could remove the parameterless constructor to avoid making the same mistake again. This way, the compiler will complain if you try to use it.